# error jest: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm testing a React Native app build with Typescript.

Jest Output:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Ps. Rn work anyway also render method, but i don't understand where is this bug in the code. Anyone can help me?

**App.test.tsx**

```js
import 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here:
[Why is my jest test failing in React native with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473512/why-is-my-jest-test-failing-in-react-native-with-typescript/61649296#61649296)

If you are using react-native with expo, add this to your package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js"
    ]
},
```