# Why is my jest test failing in React native with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I have set up a really, really simple component in react native using typescript. My goal is just  to get Jest set up and a simple test to pass. Here is the code for App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import { create } from "react-test-renderer";

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = create(<App />);
  expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

'Hello World' renders as expected but when I run the test I get:

```
  console.error
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in componen
ts) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

And indeed when I check the exported function 'App's type it is a React.Element not a component. But why is that? It is returning an element but I thought thats what a component was supposed to do. The export itself is a stateless function so I am a bit confused...

UPDATE: Dennis Tsoi added

```
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "ts",
  "tsx",
  "js"
],
```

to the 'jest' object in package.json and that fixed the typerror. It seems expo client does not create everything needed to run tpyescript in react native

Comment: What extension do you have on your test?
`.ts` or `.tsx`

Comment: .tsx but I get the same error either way

Comment: Was this project created using the react-cli? Can you post the jest config? 
And can you try `export default  App` at the end of the file instead of having it inline?

Comment: @nipuna777 the project was created with expo-cli. I storing the function in a const and got the same result (I'm wondering why you thought that would change something). I am not using a jest config, rather I have jest preset set to react-native in the package.json file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit:

From looking at the remote repository,
https://github.com/adamglang/rnTranslatedBible

The error was related a missing jest configuration in the package.json.

---

Note:

- [Github pull request](https://github.com/adamglang/rnTranslatedBible/pull/4)

---

Solution:

**package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ]
  },
```

---

According to the jest docs, 
the default configuration is:

```
Default: ["js", "json", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "node"]
```

By altering the order, whereby `"ts"` and `"tsx"` are moved infront of `js`, the issue is resolved.

---

Suggest react-native-testing-library as react-test-renderer can have some issues with react native;

**Note**: requires [react-native-testing-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library) as a devDependancy.

Commentary:

- someRN developer use react-native-testing-library as a simple way to test their components; as well as allowing methods to quickly assert values based on a deeply nested component tree.

#### Why React-native-testing-library resolves:

> You want to write maintainable tests for your React Native components without testing implementation details, but then you're told to use Enzyme, which you learn has no React Native adapter, meaning only shallow rendering is supported. And you want to render deep! But deep rendering may otherwise require jsdom (React Native isn't the web!), while doing deep rendering with react-test-renderer is so painful.

#### Example

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

test.ts

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-native-testing-library";
import App from "../App";

describe("App", () => {

  it("App", async () => {
    const component = render(<App />);
    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Edit [Attach snapshot]

```
exports[`App App 1`] = `
<View
  style={
    Object {
      "alignItems": "center",
      "backgroundColor": "#fff",
      "flex": 1,
      "justifyContent": "center",
    }
  }
>
  <Text>
    Hello World!
  </Text>
</View>
`;
```

Comment: unfortunately, this failed with the same type error

Comment: - I tried the above on an existing app i ahve - and rendered ok - I suspect it maybe related to either the react version (package.json) or perhaps to the `tsconfig`/`tsconfig.jest.json`

Comment: I attached the snapshot above - but can't think of anything - hope this helps -

Comment: @HelloWorld is it possible if you could paste a link of your repo or your package Json/tsconfig... would like to debug further

Comment: having a look now

Comment: added a PR to the repo

Comment: The change to "moduleFileExtensions" in package.json fixed the issue I was having. The other changes did not work. (Cannot find module 'jest-fetch-mock' from 'setupJest.js'). But since my question was answered and I know what is wrong you get the bounty. If you'd like to edit your answer to explain what worked please feel free

Comment: you should run `npm i` to include `jest-fetch-mock` for you devDependancies